# About NSOperationQueue, why sometimes the NSThreads' address are repetitive but sometimes are not

Tags: ios

I init 5 NSInvocationOperation and add them to a NSOperationQueue

```
 queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5;
[queue addOperation:operation1];
[queue addOperation:operation2];
[queue addOperation:operation3];
[queue addOperation:operation4];
[queue addOperation:operation5];
```

when the operations work :

```
2015-06-10 11:45:14.599 NSOperation[9596:102063] Operation1 thead:<NSThread: 0x7fe55b714fe0>{number = 9, name = (null)}
2015-06-10 11:45:14.599 NSOperation[9596:102068] Operation2 thead:<NSThread: 0x7fe55b728e50>{number = 10, name = (null)}
2015-06-10 11:45:14.599 NSOperation[9596:102069] Operation3 thead:<NSThread: 0x7fe55b737da0>{number = 11, name = (null)}
2015-06-10 11:45:14.599 NSOperation[9596:102070] Operation4 thead:<NSThread: 0x7fe55b6257c0>{number = 12, name = (null)}
2015-06-10 11:45:14.599 NSOperation[9596:102063] Operation5 thead:<NSThread: 0x7fe55b714fe0>{number = 9, name = (null)}
```

why sometimes the NSThreads' address are repetitive but sometimes are not.

Comment: According to my understanding, the API is responsible for dispatching the operation on any thread. It can be same or different.

Answer (score 0):

From `NSOperation` Document

> An operation may execute in any thread

So,sometimes two operation may run on same thread. That depends on the dispatch of NSOperationQueue.

For example,you run it on 4 core CPU,when you add 4 operation,it may create four thread so that each core run a thread. But when you add 5th operation,it just add it to an existing thread to run on a same core.

Just from my understanding.